# reverse an SQL instead of 'select from TABLE if x=y' 'delete from TABLE if y does NOT = x'

Tags: sql-server

The query is as below:

```
USE SMR_UK_DATA 
SELECT  
    MGM.MODEL_ID as ModelID,MGM.MODEL_GROUP_CODE as [Model Group Code]
    ,ISNULL(PT.HDRDESC,'') as Header,ISNULL(PT.SUBHDR1,'') as SubHeader1,ISNULL(PT.SUBHDR2,'') as SubHeader2,ISNULL(PT.INDENT0,'') as IND0,ISNULL(PT.INDENT1,'') as IND1,ISNULL(PT.INDENT2,'') as IND2,ISNULL(PT.INDENT3,'') as IND3,ISNULL(PT.INDENT4,'') as IND4,ISNULL(PT.INDENT5,'') as IND5,ISNULL(PT.INDENT6,'') as IND6,ISNULL(PT.QTY,'') as Qty,ISNULL(PT.PARTNO,'') as PartNo,PT.CURR_PRICE as Price
FROM    
    dbo.MODEL_GROUP_MEMBER MGM
    LEFT JOIN dbo.PARTS_TABLE PT ON MGM.MODEL_GROUP_CODE = PT.MODEL_GROUP_CODE
    WHERE   
    MGM.MODEL_ID = '149839'
    AND PT.HDRDESC IS NOT NULL
    --AND PT.SUBHDR1 = 'Glass - windscreen'
    ORDER BY Header,SubHeader1,SubHeader2,IND0,IND1
```

One of the tables in this query has over 40000000 rows.
I would like to trim this database down (from 45GB!) so i can move it about for testing purposes.

As it stands the output gives what I want. I would like for the query to just delete ALL of the other rows that do not.
for testing purposes I will only use the one ModelID, so I wont need the other data.

Comment: So what table do you want data deleted from? Why is your query using a `LEFT JOIN dbo.PARTS_TABLE PT ` when you use ` AND PT.HDRDESC IS NOT NULL` where condition?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you just need an anti-join, ie `NOT EXISTS`

```sql
DELETE mgm
FROM dbo.MODEL_GROUP_MEMBER mgm
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.PARTS_TABLE pt
    WHERE pt.MODEL_GROUP_CODE = mgm.MODEL_GROUP_CODE
      AND pt.HDRDESC IS NOT NULL
) AND mgm.MODEL_ID = '149839';
```